# What is asymmetry index in an array of numbers?

Tags: statistics

Someone gave me this question , and I cannot find any source that can be helpful.

> Find the asymmetry index given an array of numbers and an integer ->
>   find asymmetry index of the array

Note: I posted this question at stackoverflow, and I have been told it is related to statistic.

Can any one have some thoughts or how to answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymmetry index is the ratio of the [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) to the [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error). It is an indication of the asymmetry of a distribution. [Source](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssas/v1r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.analyticcatalyst.help%2Fanalytic_catalyst%2Fasymmetry_index.html)

Comment: can you please provide more info? stackoverflow people have already give me the link that you provided. can you mention an example? thank you

Comment: You just have to calculate the skewness and the standard error as defined in the wikipedia articles and then calculate the ratio.

Comment: which page to follow all this?

Comment: is this formula right?  3(Mean-Median) / SD

Comment: Is the 3 wanted or a typo? I think it is not the one defined in the given link, but it might be an approximation.

Comment: take a look at this link http://growingknowing.com/GKStatsBookSkewness.php

Comment: Ok the 3 is no typo, in this link they talk about the *manual formula* which is an approximation used in times where you had no access to calculators. so $\text{skewness} \approx \frac{3\text{mean}-\text{median}}{\text{sd}}$

Comment: can I use it r not?

Comment: That depends on you or your teachers, but I'd say since you have a computer you should use the correct formula, not the approximation. Keep in mind that the skewness alone is NOT the assymetry index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16263/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-flawr).